# Javascript - Getting computed values into the text area of Invoice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, invoice

So I was tasked to create an invoice.  I was able to to that, and get it to calculate the total, tax and subtotal.

What I need to do now is get the values I input into the text area.

```
<textarea  input type ="text" name = "textarea" id = "textarea" rows = "12" cols = "180"></textarea>
```

I'll put the code I have so far below.  It calculates, but I'd like my inputted values to go in the large text area I created underneath "Current Invoice".

Something like  (the content below will go in the text area)

```
---Item Code---             ---Item Name-----        ----Item Cost----     ----Quantity----    
   (user input)                  (user input)               user input             user input

---  Subtotal----                ---tax-------        ----Total------
     (calculation)               (calculation)           (calculation)
```

I'll show you my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">


        <h1>Invoice Manager</h1>

        <style type "text/css">
        div      {position: absolute;
                  top: 200px;
                  left: 90px;
                  z-index: 1;}
        l         
        </style>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">


        function computeCost(){
            var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
            var code = code; // item code

            var itemName = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
            var itemName = itemName; // item name

            var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;
            var cost = cost; // calculate cost 

            var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
            var quantity = quantity; // calculate quantity of items

            var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value;
            var subtotal = cost * quantity; // multiplying cost by quantity = subtotal

            var tax = document.getElementById("tax").value;
            var tax = subtotal * .07; // multiplying subtotal by tax(.7) = amount of tax owed

            var total = document.getElementById("total").value;
            var total = tax + subtotal; //adding tax to subtotal = total value

            var textContent = document.getElementById("textarea").value;





            document.getElementById("subtotal").value = subtotal;

            document.getElementById("tax").value = tax;

            document.getElementById("total").value = total;

            document.getElementById("textContent").value = textContent;


        }


        </script>



    <body>

    <form action = ""method = "post" name = "myForm">   
        <table>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Item Code:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "code" id="code" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Item Name:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "itemName" id="itemName" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Item Cost:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "cost" id="cost" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Quantity:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "quantity" id="quantity" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>

     <br></br> <br></br>
    <font size = "5">Current Invoice</font>

    <hr style = "height:2px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;"></hr>

    <textarea  input type ="text" name = "textarea" id = "textarea" rows = "12" cols = "180"></textarea>
    </label>




            <table>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Subtotal:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "subtotal" id="subtotal" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Sales Tax:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "tax" id="tax" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right">Total:</td>
              <td align="left"><input type="text" name = "total" id="total" /></td>
            </tr>

          </table>
    </form>




      <form>
        <div id="AddItemButton">
            <td align = "left"><input type="button" value= "Add Item" id = "add" onclick="computeCost();"/>
            <td> 
        </div>
      </form>




</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?  I'm struggling to get my inputting values in the text area.

I've tried calling 'getElementById(input = 'text').value;'   But that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's what I have for the textarea

Seems to work ok

```
document.getElementById('textarea').value =  "--" + code + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + "--" + itemName + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + cost +"--" + " " + " " + "--" + quantity + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + subtotal + "--" + " " + " " + " " + "--" + tax + "--" + " " + " " + "--" + total + "--";
```

It might not be proper code tho.

Comment: When calling, `getElementById` it expects the `id` attribute of the element you are interested in. In the case of your `textarea` element, you have the `id='textarea'`. To help clear up some of your confusion, why would you believe that, `getElementById(input='text')` would work?

Comment: Not sure.  I figured since every input value = "text", I could call all the input values named "text" like that.  So then when I did that, everything I typed would be transferred to the Text area.  Now that I look at that, there's nothign there that makes it go to the text area.  I had a bunch of stuff I tried, but deleted.   That was just off the top of my head.   One time I tried something (don't remember what it was) but I got '[object HTMLTextAreaElement]' into the text area, but not the value I inputted.

Comment: It would appear that your attempt when returning the element object (ie, `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]`) you were halfway there. By calling, `getElementById('textarea')` you are only returning the DOM element containing the `id` attribute of `textarea`. The next piece (which I see in your `computeCost` function) would be to access the `value` property of that DOM element to retrieve the value.

Comment: repeating `var` for the same variable names is asking for all sorts of unexpected problems. WHY do you want this all in a textarea in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl -- The assignment calls for it.  I need to figure out a way to put my inputted values in the large text area I created.

Comment: @ Anthony .. Wish I remember what I did lol.  I could probably retrace my steps

Comment: @user3577397 The `value` property of a DOM element drives what is stored inside of that element. This property can be retrieved and can be used to assign values which you want to appear in that element. Does that help? My efforts are to allow you to arrive to the answer yourself as a learning exercise.

Comment: ok..sounds reasonable. In real world it wouldn't make much sense

Comment: @AnthonyForloney  Do you mean I could do 'document.getElementById('subtotal', 'tax', 'total');'?   Or do you mean put the computeCost function in there?

Comment: @user3577397 Neither. The `getElementById` function takes a single `id` attribute of a given element. What are you hoping to achieve, assigning a value into your `textarea` DOM element? That can be done through utilzing, `getElementById` with the `id` attribute for **that** `textarea` DOM element. Once you have the DOM element, you can take it one step further and assign value(s) to it's `.value` property (ie, `document.getElementById('textarea').value = "blahblah"`)

Comment: @charlietfl  I got rid of the extra variables, and I was able to get the subtotal in the textarea.  But I want all the inputted values, especially the user inputted values

Comment: @AnthonyForloney I tried that too Anthony.  I had 'document.getElementById('textarea').value = text; and the subtotal went into the text area. I probably didn't do it correctly tho

Comment: you will have to concatenate all of the data (text) and then set the value. Spacing it will be tricky in a textarea to get desired layout shown

Comment: Hey guys I just did this 'document.getElementById('textarea').value = id = code + itemName+ cost + quantity + subtotal + tax + total;'  and it kind of worked.  The formatting looks like garbage tho.  Is that the right idea?

Comment: @user3577397 You are on the right track with concatenation. Although the assignment to the `id` variable, along with the `code + itemName + cost + quantity ... + total` variable(s) is not correct; did you mean to concatenate `id` instead of assigning it?

Comment: I was just experimenting. I took away the id, and it worked still.  @AnthonyForloney   Not sure if it's proper code, but it seems to work.  I'll put what I have above under "edit"      One thing though, each time I click "add item" it's supposed to save to the text area.  Right now it adds it, but then when I input new values, it replaces the old ones.

Comment: @AnthonyForloney,I get it to add the values to the text area, but I want it to keep adding values every time I hit "add item".  Right now it just replaces it. How do I get it to keep adding values every time I hit "add item"?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney,I'm trying to figure out what you said about DOM elements earlier, like assigning Textarea a Dom (It's id = 'textarea'), I believe, and then calling it, but I'm having trouble

Comment: @user3577397 I apologize for my confusion, what are you trying to achieve to do exactly?

Comment: Np, it's not your fault, it's my inability to understand this stuff. Basically, I'm trying to hit "add item" button and each time I do that, the values go into the Text Area horizontally.  If put more values in, those values go underneath the previous values.  So the user gets to see all the values he/she entered, like item name, cost, etc, and at the bottom of the page, my subtotal, tax and total calculates a everything that person enters.  It's supposed to be an invoice

Comment: @user3577397 If your goal would be to take the current value of whats stored inside the `textarea` and keep appending items to it, then all that is required would be to store off the `.value` property (ie, `var currentText = document.getElementById('textarea').value`) and then assign the `.value` property to the `currentText` plus anything else (ie, `document.getElementById('textarea').value = currentValue + '\nSome more text!'` -- notice the `\n` which can be used for entering a new line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some formatting on your textarea, you can use [TINYMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

you can append html elements on your textarea.

Comment: I'll try this thanks.   This is just a guess, but would my textarea look like "<textarea input type = "text" name = "textarea" id = subtotal + total + itemName +quantity etc. ?